# SQLSTATE[23000] Integrity constraint voilation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null (ANDROID-MYSQL)

Tags: php, android, mysql

**NOTE: New to android**

Sorry about this I know there are lot of searches about this but still couldn't find why it is giving me an error.

Here's my code on Android

```
public static final String KEY_TEXT_USERNAME = "username";
private TextView _username;


_username = findViewById(R.id.user_username);
```

this is how I get my username from login fragment

```
 //GET DATA FROM INTENT (LOGIN FRAGMENT)
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if(bundle != null)
{
    String j = bundle.getString("userinfo");
    _username.setText("HI " + j);
}
```

Now I pass this data like this

```
String txtUsername = _username.getText().toString().trim();
data.put(KEY_TEXT_USERNAME, txtUsername);
String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data);
return result;
```

Now going to PHP

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
if($user->UploadFiles($username))
{
    echo "Success";
}
else
{
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Now my UploadFiles()

```
public function UploadFiles($username)
{
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_profile(username) VALUES(:username)");
  $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);
  $stmt->execute();

  return $stmt;
}
```

This error keeps appearing

> SQLSTATE[23000] Integrity constraint voilation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null

I've been investigating this for like an hour now and I gave up so I came here to ask some assistance . Thank you in advance .

#ADDITIONAL DEBUGGING

tried using `var_dump($username);` on my php and it is not null it contains the string username that I get from my android app.

here's a proof

[image]

I tried also dropping the column and add again then it gives me this error

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised you get a  database error. Your code should throw a syntax error before it tries to insert anything. This: `"INSERT INTO user_profile(username) VALUES(":username")"` is invalid syntax and should be `"INSERT INTO user_profile(username) VALUES(:username)"`

Comment: You can also do `var_dump($_POST)` to check that PHP gets the values you expect.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry about that I type it all out there's no "" in my code

Comment: There's is a value on my username @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Please copy/paste the actual code without rewrites. It's OK to remove unrelated code. Helping debug rewrites is usually pointless since you, not only might introduce new issues like the one I pointed out, but you can also accidentally and unknowingly solve your own issue, leaving us just confused about the question.

Comment: Sorry about that but it's all good now the problem still exist and also there's a value on my username already tried var dump earlier

Comment: If you've checked that `$username` contains a string, then I don't see how it can be null. Have you debugged (dumped) that variable everywhere you're using it? Specifically inside the method `UploadFiles()` (strange name considering what it does though.) Can you add the output of `var_dump($_POST)` to your question for a request that doesn't work?

Comment: Please add the actual output of var_dump($_POST) to your post instead of just saying it looks ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a big mistake on my end. Probably I did not notice that my `library.php` which has the function `UploadFiles` was on the other file so I was editing on the wrong directory that is why it was not updating. I'm very sorry about this noob mistake.

Please tell me if I should delete this post or not.
Thank you for understanding.